# MariaDB CONNECT engine to read external mongodb collections

Tags: mongodb, mariadb, mariadb-10.3, storage-engine

I want to access MongoDB collections through MariaDB 10.4.17. Both are installed on my local machine running Windows 10.

| Software | listening port |
| --- | --- |
| MongoDB | 27017 |
| MariaDB | 15501 |

I installed the MariaDB Connect Engine using

```
INSTALL SONAME 'ha_connect';
```

on the MariaDB CLI

The collection I want to access is named `receptors` and has documents like these

```json
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "taste" : "Umami",
  "receptor_name" : "mGluR4",
  "uniprot_id" : "Q14833"
}
```

this is the create table statement I used on mariadb

```sql
CREATE TABLE receptors (
  _id varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  taste varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  receptor_name varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  uniprot_id varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=CONNECT DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
  CONNECTION='mongodb://localhost:27017'
  table_type=MONGO tabname='receptors' data_charset=utf8
```

The table was created, but when I execute

```
SELECT * FROM receptors
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1296 (HY000): Got error 174 'Error 126 loading module jvm.dll: The specified module could not be found. ' from CONNECT
```

I fixed it by giving a path to JVM like this

```bash
set global connect_jvm_path="C://Program Files//Java//jdk-12.0.1//bin//server"
```

Next error I got is this which I am unable to figure out

```
ERROR 1296 (HY000): Got error 174 'ERROR: class wrappers/Mongo3Interface not found!' from CONNECT
```

I have the JavaWrappers file here: `C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.4\lib\plugin`

It should contain the Mongo3Interface but does not.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, and the MariaDB documentation isn't much help.

Answer (score 0):

Per [doc](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-mongo-table-type/#using-the-mongo-java-driver) set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable or `connect_class_path` system server variable to `C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.4\lib\plugin`

Note: [10.3.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-1032-release-notes/) was an Alpha release and is not recommended for use.

Also: Why do you have a JavaWrapper directory that lists MariaDB-10.4 when you say you are running 10.3?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update that part of the question, changing that rn, I was using 10.3.2 earlier then upgraded to 10.4.17, I will try this solution and get back to you

Comment: Even after setting class path  like this  

"set global connect_class_path="C://Program Files//MariaDB 10.4//lib//plugin";"

the same error persists